Dual display issue on Ubuntu 24.04
Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 on my Framework, I'm running into issues when connecting a second monitor with HDMI. The laptop screen starts flickering and freezing sometimes, while the external monitor works just fine.

There is no problem when no display is connected
This issue does not appear when mirroring the laptop screen, only with "Join" display.
Issue dissapears when unconnecting the external display.
There was no issue with that monitor prior to upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Here's some info about my build. BIOS, fw and sw are all up-to-date:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core) A8
Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic
Uptime: 1 hour, 22 mins
Packages: 2668 (dpkg), 15 (flatpak), 31 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.2.21
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-1280P (20) @ 4.700GHz
GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
Memory: 11079MiB / 15698MiB


I'm facing the same issue, tried different things for hours without success

I had the same issue and I solved by changing the refresh rate of the HDMI external monitor to 59.94 Hz

I'm using several monitors and it works for some but not always.
